# AngularJS - Access $statParams from a parent controller with UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router

I have a rather complicated prototype app that I have been asked to throw together... now in my app I have some routes / states defined using UI-Router, here is some code from my app.js file, you can see one parent and child route / state:

```
.state('myapp.loggedInHome.contacts.default', {
        url: '/:profileId', // this could be myurl.com/home/contacts/31333194
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        publicAccess: false
    })
// nested state for contacts profile...
.state('myapp.loggedInHome.contacts.default.news', {
    url: '/news',  // this could be myurl.com/home/contacts/31333194/news
    templateUrl: '/prototype/app/people/views/news.html',
    publicAccess: false,
    controller: 'VisitorsNewsCtrl'
})
```

Now in the `VisitorsNewsCtr`l controller I want to access the `:profileId` as defined in the parent root... however when I try to access this using the `$stateParams` service I get `undefined`! What am I doing wrong in my controller?

```
.controller('VisitorsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams) {

      console.log($stateParams.profileId); // this is undefined as 
                                           // $stateParams is an empty object
```

I am redirecting to this state like so...

`$state.go('myapp.loggedInHome.contacts.default.news', { profileId: 123456 } );`

however the value for `profileId` is undefined? But the value appears in the URL!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the potential params to the url in your state definition like this:
`url: '/news/:profileId'`

If you use `$state.go('myapp.loggedInHome.contacts.default.news', {profileId: 1234})` you should then be able to access `$stateParams.profileId`

Example definition:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
            expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the value by using the `$state` object!

Like so...

```
.controller('VisitorsCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {

console.log($state.params.profileId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly (despite two other answers) the problem is, that this defintion:

```
.controller('VisitorsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
  function ($scope, $stateParams) {

    console.log($stateParams.profileId); 
    ...
```

Is about controller `'VisitorsCtrl'`. While the state says **`'VisitorsNewsCtrl'`**:

```
.state('myapp.loggedInHome.contacts.default.news', {
    url: '/news',  // this could be myurl.com/home/contacts/31333194/news
    templateUrl: '/prototype/app/people/views/news.html',
    publicAccess: false,
    controller: 'VisitorsNewsCtrl'
})
```

So, if the controller will match I am sure that the syntax with $stateParams will work